# Triangle Mesh, unable to add object to scene in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm working on importing a 3D model (obj file) and using JavaFX triangle mesh to add it to the scene.

first, I read the obj file, parse it and save its content to (float array "Vertices", and integer array for "Faces". My mesh points :[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], and mesh faces : [1, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0,........]

and then I add it to my scene

```
    MeshView cubeMesh = new MeshView(mesh);
    cubeMesh.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
    cubeMesh.setTranslateX(20);
    cubeMesh.setTranslateY(10);
    cubeMesh.setTranslateZ(20);

    displayPane.getChildren().add(cubeMesh);
```

Unfortunately, nothing is added to the scene. Would anybody be able to suggest a solution, tutorial or a book?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an initial tutorial directly from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm